# How do I disable a button with an ng-disabled directive without adding an extra parameter to the ng-disabled directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, angularjs-directive, directive

** SHORT VERSION **

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC Web project, using AngularJS. I currently have a button with a ng-disabled directive that we want to disable in the typescript controller of that view. We currently have the following line for the button:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn-move" ng-show="main.actionType === 20" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="main.isLoading">Move</button>
```

Unfortunately, because of the ng-disabled, using something like

```
var actionButton = $("#btn-move");       
actionButton.disabled = true;
```

or

```
var actionButton = $("#btn-move");       
actionButton.prop("disabled", true);
```

doesn't work. We don't want to add an additional variable to the ng-disabled like ng-disabled="main.isLoading || main.actionButtonDisabled".

** LONG VERSION **

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC Web project, using AngularJS. 
To perform certain actions, the users of the application have to open a popup (ngDialog) with a form in it. The user will fill in the form and next click on submit (or press Enter) and the form will be submitted. The view uses an Angular controller (with typescript).

The data from the form is send to our back end where it is processed. When the processing is done, the back end sends us the result back. The result contains 3 elements: A boolean for success, an Array (of strings) for Errors, and an array of strings for Warnings.

- The success boolean tells us if the action was succesfully processed,
  meaning the form was correctly filled in and the action was allowed.
- The Error array has Errors aimed for the user. These errors can be
  something like: "You can't move item X to location Y." Whenever
  there're errors, the action was unsuccessful and the success boolean
  will be false.
- The warnings array has warnings for the user, but having warnings
  doesn't mean that the action has failed. So having warnings means
  that the action could still be a success.

Whenever the success boolean is true, we close the popup. Whenever the success boolean is false, we don't close the popup and show the warnings / errors to the user. We use the following code for this:

```
private move = () => {
        var model = new Classes.InventoryItem.ManipulateStockOptions();
        model.articleId = this.articleId;
        model.quantity = this.quantity;
        model.locationFromId = this.locationId;

        this.inventoryItemService.manipulateStock(model).then((data: PerformActionResult) => {

            this.warnings = data.warnings;
            this.errors = data.errors;

            this.isLoading = false;

            if (data.success) {
                this.$scope.closeThisDialog();
            }
        });
```

Now, here's what we want to change:

Whenever there're warnings but the success bool is true, we want the warnings to be shown, keep the popup open and disable the action button. Now the first two aren't a problem. The problem comes when we want to disable the button.

We currently have the following line for the button:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn-move" ng-show="main.actionType === 20" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="main.isLoading">Move</button>
```

Unfortunately, because of the ng-disabled, using something like

```
var actionButton = $("#btn-move");       
actionButton.disabled = true;
```

or

```
var actionButton = $("#btn-move");       
actionButton.prop("disabled", true);
```

don't work. Technically, we could add another variable to the scope and add it to the ng-disabled clause, but we don't want to do that. In our application, we've got a lot of these popup forms and we don't want to add a new variable to each one of those.

We've also tried using a directive, but this didn't solve the problem of not having to add another variable to each scope.

The directive:

```
<button type="submit" id="{{btnid}}" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="isLoading || actionButtonDisabled">
    {{label}}
</button>
```

with this controller

```
module App.Directives.ActionButton {

// #region interfaces

export interface IActionButtonScope extends ng.IScope {

    isLoading: boolean;
    actionButtonDisabled: boolean;
    label: string;
    btnid: string;
}

// #endregion

// #region directive

export class ActionButton implements ng.IDirective {

    public restrict = 'AE';
    public replace = true;
    public transclude = true;
    public templateUrl = Constants.TEMPLATE_URL + 'action-button.html';

    public $scope = {
        isLoading: '=',
        actionButtonDisabled: '=',
        label: '@',
        btnid: '='
    }
}

// #endregion

App.Module.directive('actionButton', [() => new ActionButton()])
}
```

and implemented like this:

```
  <action-button btnid="btn-move" ng-show="main.actionType === 10" isLoading="main.isLoading" label="Move"></action-button>
```

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Have considered just adding/removing a css class that disables the button? You can use pointer-event: none to get the same beaviour

Comment: That did the trick. I added 
`actionButton.addClass('disabled');` and now the button gets disabled.

Comment: Apparently, this doesn't do what I wanted. When hovering over the button, it shown the disabled cursor, but you can still click on it.

Comment: Did you add `pointer-events: none;` in your `disabled` css class?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your second response. I did forget to add that line of code. However, with that line of code, it removes the hover feature, and when hovering over the button, you no longer get the not-allowed cursor. Instead you get the regular arrow cursor. Do you know of a way to have both the button not be clickable and the cursor showing the not-allowed sign? Thank you.

Comment: You can control the cursor being shown. Check this out: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_class_cursor.asp. You can choose what cursor and style you want when it's hovering and when it's not hovering.